# Is the alternating sum of prime numbers $2-3 + 5-7 \dots$ asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2}p_k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I tried to show that $|2-3 + \dots (-1) ^ {N + 1} p_N| \sim \frac{1}{2}p_N$ but I don't know if what I did holds. I would be very interested in getting advice. At the end of the question there is a bonus speculation which is both very stupid and interesting, at least, from my point of view...

$p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number, expanding the inverse function of the logarithmic integral for $k\geq2$ we get:
$$p_k= k \ln(k)+k \ln(\ln(k))-k+O\left(\frac{k }{\ln(k)}\ln(\ln(k))\right)$$

I wonder if it is correct to sum over the big $O$ notation and exploit the algebra of this notation
$$O\left((-1)^{N+1}\frac{N \ln\ln N}{\ln(N)}\right)+O\left((-1)^{N}\frac{(N-1) \ln\ln (N-1)}{\ln(N-1)}\right)+\dots=O\left(\frac{(N) \ln\ln (N)}{\ln(N)}\right)$$

If this is legit, we can write
$$\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{k+1}p_k=\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{k+1} k \ln(k)+\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{k+1} k \ln\ln(k)-\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{k+1} k +O\left(\frac{N \ln\ln N}{\ln(N)}\right)$$

To estimate the value of these sums, let's set $ N = 2x + 1 $
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2x+1}(-1)^{k+1}k \ln(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{x+1} (2k-1) \ln(2k-1)-\sum_{k=1}^x 2k \ln(2k)=\\\sum_{k=1}^{x+1} 2k \ln(1-\frac{1}{2k})-\sum_{k=1}^{x+1}  \ln(2k-1)+2(x+1)\ln(2(x+1)).$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{x+1}  \ln(2k-1)=(x+1)\ln(2)+\ln\left((x+\frac{1}{2})!\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\pi)$$

The Lauren series for $y \ln(1-\frac{1}{y})$ for $y\to \infty$ is:$\ \ -1-\frac{1}{2y}-\frac{1}{3y^2}-\frac{1}{4y^3}+O(y^{-4})$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{x+1} 2k \ln(1-\frac{1}{2k})\sim -(x+1)-\frac{1}{4}H_{x+1}-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{2^k(k+1)}$$
$H$ is the  [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_{x+1}\sim\ln(x+1)+\gamma$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{x+1} 2k \ln(1-\frac{1}{2k})=-x+O(\ln(x))$$

By the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) : $\ln(y!)\sim y \ln(y)-y+O(\ln(y))$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{x+1}  \ln(2k-1)= x (\ln(x)+\ln(2)-1)+O(\ln(x))$$

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{k+1} k \ln(k)\right|\sim n \ln(2n)+O(\ln(n))$$
In the same way we can estimate
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{k+1}k \ln(\ln(k))\right|= n\ln(\ln(2n))+O\left(\ln(\ln(n))\right)$$
and
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k+1}k\right|=n+1$$

> $$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{k+1}p_k\right|=n\Big( \ln(2n)+\ln(\ln(2n)-1\Big)+O\left(\frac{n \ln\ln(n)}{\ln(n)}\right) $$

[image]

or in other words

> $$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^{N}(-1)^{k+1}p_k\right|=\frac{N}{2}\Big( \ln(N)+\ln(\ln(N)-1\Big)+O\left(\frac{N \ln\ln(N)}{\ln(N)}\right) .$$

Basically this means that the absolute value of the sum oscillates around $\frac{P_N}{2}$

$$S(x)=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{x}(-1)^{k+1}p_k\right|-\frac{p_x}{2}$$
Therefore the function $S(x)$ will have no limit for $x \to\infty$ but will oscillate around the abscissa axis as if it were a sound wave. Who knows, maybe there is some way to code the $S$ function in some music software to know how the prime numbers sounds like.

[image]

Comment: Numerical analysis in larger ranges seems very promising. For $17\ 400 \le p\le 10^9$ , the value of $$|\frac{2-3+5-7+11-13\cdots \pm p}{p}|$$ lies between $0.493$ and $0.507$

Comment: And if $p\ge 8.6\cdot 10^6$, the value seems to lie always between $0.499$ and $0.501$ (upto $10^9$ , there is no counterexample)

Comment: @Peter very reassuring, what software to use to sum $p$ up to $10 ^ 9$? 
thanks ;)

Comment: I used PARI/GP and used a little trick to avoid to have to calculate the n-th prime. The code I used is : s=0;z=-1;forprime(t=1,10^9,z=-z;s=s+z*t;r=abs(s/t);if(t>10^4,if(r<0.499,print(t,"   ",r*1.0))))  and the analogue code for ">0.501"

Comment: You can also use Euler–Boole summation to arrive at your formula.

Comment: @Gary I don't know what it is, if you explain it to me in an answer, I'll vote it

Comment: @PatrickDanzi Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Boole_summation

Comment: @Gary I looked at it,  but I don't know what $m$ is and I don't know how to interpret the derivative of $p_k$ (maybe $p'_k\sim\ln(p_k)$ using the definition of derivative of the inverse function applied to the logarithmic integral $li(x)$) .. but for me it's not immediate / practical  to go from Wikipedia to the result you told me about

Comment: I meant the part when after approximating $p_k$. So you can take $
f(x) = x\log x + x\log \log x - x$ and $m=2$ in the Euler–Boole summation formula.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mathematicians believe that It should by asymptotic to $\frac{p_x}{2}$ but its not proven, the best unconditional lower bound is $\frac{p_x}{64}$ and the conditional lower bound is $\frac{p_x}{8}$ assuming Hardy-Littlewood conjecture.

The problem with your analysis is that if $f(x)  \sim g(x)$ that does not mean that $ |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} f(k) |  \sim  |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} g(k) |$ for instance $f(x)=x+(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x$

And so $ |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k g(k)| \sim \frac{n}{2} \not \sim \frac{n \sqrt{n}}{6} \sim |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k f(k)|$

The summation in this question boils down to the gap between consecutive primes $g_k$ which we don't know that much about it.

Comment: $ |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} f(k) | \not \sim  |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} g(k) |$ this makes perfect sense, but in my case I have not only the information $ f (x) \sim g (x) $ but I also have information on the remainder $ f (x) = r (x) + O (h (x)) $. my "proof" is based on the fact that $ O (h (N)) + O (h (N-1))+\dots =O(h(N)) $. Is this statement about the sum incorrect?

Comment: In your example, $ f (x) $ cannot be written as $ f (x) = x + O (h (x)) $, it can only be written as $ f (x) = O (x) $, thus making the attempt to compare it with the sum of $ g (x) = x $  vain. However, now I try to update what I have done, trying to make it more solid by using the squeeze theorem

Comment: you don't have information about the remainder because according to Baker $g_n \leq n^{0.55} $ and if we assume R.H. then it only gets slightly better namely $g_n \leq n^{0.5} \ln {n}$ , also in my example $f(x) \sim g(x) $ because $f(x)= x + O(\sqrt{x})$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = 0$

Comment: Can you give a citation for "mathematicians believe that it should be asymptotic to $p_x/2$"? While I agree that should be the typical behavior, "asymptotic" is a very strong assertion.

Comment: @PatrickDanzi The error is in the way you estimate the error term. Say $p_k = k\log k+k\log\log k-k+r(k)$. We know that $|r(k)|<C k\log\log k/\log k$, but $r(k)$ can well be negative for certain $k$'s. So the best you can say is that $$
\left| {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {( - 1)^k r(k)} } \right| \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left| {r(k)} \right|} .
$$

Comment: now i get it, thanks for the advice